# The Maze inside the head of the Host

Tags: plot-explanation, westworld-tv

In season 1 of *[Westworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westworld_(TV_series))* we saw the Maze in some places.

The Maze shows up on the inside of Kissy's scalp when being scalped by Man in Black, after the man in black traumatizes *Maeve*, she runs out and falls with a maze somehow magically appearing around her , its on a box in a train in that scene with Dolores, and there was one scene with a host carving it on a table.

[image]

As in Season 2 Episode 1, we again see the Maze in some other Host's head. So is there a Maze drawn inside every Host's head? Or is is just a chosen few ?

Or as this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/westworld/comments/7hdr9q/why_do_mazes_appear_in_westworld/) discussion says, it appear only when the hosts feel fear and suffer??.

Comment: you should watch the series further, where you will get the answer to this question.

Answer (score 8):

In S2E8

> members of the Ghost Nation scalp each other, draw the symbol inside, then their scalps are presumably reattached by Delos technicians who never notice. Every subsequent appearance of the maze has been inscribed by one of them, including the one outside Maeve's house

Answer (score -5):

No, there is nothing like chosen ones. And no, the maze is not drawn inside every host's head.

The maze is drawn inside only those hosts which were created by Arnold himself.
Because Arnold was concerned or obsessed with consciousness, he made a way to get that into hosts.

Like Dolores solved the maze in Season 1 and got the consciousness.

Found this [here](https://www.bustle.com/p/whats-in-the-hosts-brains-on-westworld-the-spherical-technology-is-frighteningly-powerful-8849696)

Comment: Do you have any evidence for these assertions?

Comment: It's also unclear if Dolores is really conscious (if there's more stages?), because of the way Journey into Night is playing out, including that there is still a game for William, "The Door". There are lots of androids still on loops or do not seemed concerned with the bigger picture. Dolores is also enacting a Eugenics movement where her critera for who lives and who dies has not been explained (to the audience) yet. We also just got some confirmation on other "types" of hosts, and so it stands to reason that some may be more special or capable of achieving self determination, than others...